# Django admin overriding - adding a print button

Tags: python, django, printing, django-admin

I would like to create a "print button" inside an app in django admin interface to load a page in another browser tab (a view that is already coded) and let the user print it directly from admin interface.

I used the override to add a "print" button near the "history" button following this example: 
[overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

I have a model named "Card", each card has a unique number which is used to load a corresponding view, now I need to take this number and pass it to the print button to redirect to the page I want to print. How to get it?

I tried this

`<a href="{{ ROOT_URL }}/my_app/{{ card.number }}" class="historylink">Print</a>`

but it redirect to the root directory and doesn't take the value I need from the model.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using django-object-actions app, it allows adding actions with custom logic to django-admin.

You can find it here: https://github.com/texastribune/django-object-actions

**Installlation:** 
1) `pip install django-object-actions` 
2) add `django_object_actions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: thank you, clould you please provide a step-by-step installation guide? I'm new to django extensions-