# Django: How to add a print button to objects to print some (special) fields of a model instance

Tags: django

**(Hopefully) not a duplicate:**

I know this might seem to be quite similar to [Django admin overriding - adding a print button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476195/django-admin-overriding-adding-a-print-button)
But the answer there is to use django-object-actions, which I already tried but it looks a bit too overloaded for such an simple task. Furthermore the buttons there are not placed behind the row.

---

**My question:**

I would like to create a printable view of some fields of a Django models instance.

Let's say I want to print an users

- Name
- Last Name
- Number

**What I image is something like this:**

1. Clicking on a `print` button, shown at the list view:

   [image]
2. An preformatted and easy to print website opens which contains the data:

   [image]

**What I have so far**

I added the button by using the following code:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('number', 'name', 'last_name', ..., 'account_actions')

    ...

    def account_actions(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<form method="post" action="/print_view.htm"> \
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{}"> \
                <button type="submit" name="action">Print</button> \
            </form>',
            obj.name
        )
    account_actions.short_description = 'Actions'
    account_actions.allow_tags = True
```

So my idea is to send the data which I want to get printed to another Website (via POST, on the same server). I would extract the data from the request then and create a printable view.

---

My question is:
**Is it possible to do the same within Django (without leaving DjangoAdmin for the printable view)?**

The current approach doesn't feel right too me, I bet there is a way to do that using just Django - a way which I don't know of since I am quite a beginner here.

Comment: Hi @ataraxis, may I ask how did you implement the below answer? this is what I really need. I am very new to django. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great module out there that is called `django-admin-object-actions`, it can be found here: https://github.com/ninemoreminutes/django-admin-object-actions

The maintainer/owner @cchurch helped me out with the following answer:

> You can specify a custom view method that can render any template or
>   return any content you'd like. Here's the simplest example I can come
>   up with to do that:
>
> ```
> class TestModelAdmin(ModelAdminObjectActionsMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
>
>     # all of the normal model admin code here
>
>     object_actions = [
>         {
>             'slug': 'print',
>             'verbose_name': _('Print'),
>             'form_method': 'GET',
>             'view': 'print_view',
>         },
>     ]
>
>     def print_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None, action=None):
>         from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
>         obj = self.get_object(request, object_id)
>         return TemplateResponse(request, 'print.html', {'obj': obj})
> ```
>
> Using the following template (print.html):
>
> ```
> <p>Name: {{ obj.name }}</p>
> <p>Enabled: {{ obj.enabled }}</p>
> ```